# How can I kill a cron program?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I am using a cron command in Ubuntu that is running a python program:

```
05 23 * * * python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
```

How do I stop the program from running?

Comment: What is wrong with using ps to get the PID (with grep to pick out the name) and then issuing a kill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal, run

```
$ ps aux | grep hello.py
```

It'll show an output like this -

```
username   NNNN  0.0  0.0  13648   940 pts/7    S+   01:04   0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
```

Where NNNN is the process ID. Then just execute -

```
$ sudo kill -9 NNNN
```

That should kill the process. Then remove it from cron if you don't want to do this again.

Comment: Thanks. but it showed three process as follows

ahmed@unist:~$ ps aux | grep hello.py
ahmed     3624  0.0  0.0   4440   628 ?        Ss   23:05   0:00 /bin/sh -c python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
ahmed     3625  9.4  1.5 205852 62436 ?        S    23:05   2:59 python /home/ahmed/Desktop/hello.py
ahmed     3925  0.0  0.0  15128   956 pts/3    S+   23:36   0:00 grep hello.py
ahmed@unist:~$ sudo 3624

Comment: the first two are the same file running, last one is for the command you just executed. Kill the first two.

Comment: thanks. just for some extra info. even after i killed the process and then checked the process using the ps aux command it shows ahmed     3956  0.0  0.0  15124   956 pts/1    S+   23:41   0:00 grep hello.py

Comment: why is that? can u explain more a bit please

Comment: Like I said in the last comment, and just as you can see in the output, that's the command you're executing. The `ps aux | grep hello.py` itself is the process you see there.